# Adding trim when walls aren't straight?

Tags: trim, old-house, built-ins, uneven

I'm doing a custom built-in in my house and as it being an old house the walls are not plumb. The cabinet is straight, level and plumb, but there's an inch difference against the wall from the top and bottom. Short of shimming the wall out and recovering (not going to do that), I was hoping someone might have ideas how I could design trim to minimize the appearance of the uneven depth. I don't expect to hide it completely but maybe make it less noticeable.

[image]

Comment: Any chance of shaving the cabinet to match the wall?  One inch is quite a bit to hide with just trim, in short distance.

Comment: *"The cabinet is straight, level and plumb"* ...well there's your problem. You fight the house, the house wins, if the house has decided to be crooked, un-level, and un-plumb, as most do (really, the majority start there if you look closely. The older ones may have moved some, too, or may simply have never bothered to worry about it from the start.)

Answer (score 2):

Make the box un-plumb to match the wall. Then if you are putting shelves in the box make them level. With items on the shelves, the box being out of plumb will not be noticed.

Comment: Added bonus: the doors close automatically from 89°. (You might want soft close hinges.)

Comment: This wall used to be the exterior front of the house until an addition was done (back in the 80s I think). That being said, the wall is cinderblock up through the 2nd floor.

I tilted the top back so it lines up with the wall. On the backside (this cabinet passes between two rooms, it's a Narnia type kind of thing) this then lined up with that side of the wall as well.   The tradeoff here was the bottom and tops are now unlevel but I don't think that will be nearly as noticeable if at all.  And I'll likely need magnetic latches to keep doors closed.

No shelves, just a rod for clothes.